# how to add List<string> in Session state

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

Is there a way to add List in session? or any other way to pass the values of List in another page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
List<string> ast = new List<string>();
        ast.Add("asdas!");
        Session["stringList"] = ast;
        List<string> bst = (List<string>)Session["stringList"];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do these kinds of things, if this is what you are asking.

```
Session["key"] = List<string>;
```

as well as

```
myStrings = (List<string>)Session["key"];
```

Comment: Session["key"] as List<string> is better. And remember to check if it's null before convertion.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to explore the following two extensions method for HttpSessionState class.

```
    public static System.Nullable<T> GetValue<T>(this HttpSessionState session, string key) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        object value = session[key];
        if (value != null && value is T)
        {
            return (T)value;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }


    public static T GetValue<T>(this HttpSessionState session, string key, T defaultValue) where T : class
    {
        object value = session[key] ?? defaultValue;
        if (value != null && value is T)
        {
            return (T)value;
        }
        else
            return default(T);
    }
```

The former is for value type and the latter is for reference type.

The usage is as follows:

```
   int? _customerId = Session.GetValue<int>("CustomerID");
   Customer _customer = Session.GetValue<Customer>("CurrentCustomer", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
var myList=(List<String>)Session["toList"];
```