# scoping issue in mvc view causing IList<t> to fail (was: how to instantiate list<t> in mvc view)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generic-collections

i have a Session var that has a List such that:

```
Session["roles"] = UserManager.GetRoles(uid) as List<string>;
```

that totally works
but now i want to use it in my layout such that:

```
@{
List<string> rolz = Session["roles"] as List<string>;
}@
```

and unfortunately i keep getting this err:
using the generic type "system.collections.generic.list" requires 1 type arguments

i see examples of passing lists over
but how do i use a preexisting session var that is already a list?

UPDATE 1:
pls note:
im interested in retrieving the Session["roles"] IN THE VIEW
not in another controller
as such the view is spitting up the error 
because i do not think it likes this syntax "List"
because when im coding it it keeps trying to intellisense it like this:

```
List<string></string>
```

UPDATE 2: title has been adjusted to reflect the correct nature of this question

Comment: Have you tried: `List&lt;string&gt; rolz = (List&lt;string&gt;)Session[&quot;roles&quot;];`. Direct casting to list of strings. And why list and not an array? :) Edit: Commenting using mobile app so there is no live comments. Sorry @Valkyriee for the almost same comment.

Comment: `UserManager.GetRoles` return an `IList<string>`

Comment: @nkosi - yes it does return an ilist but if you notice - i do a legit cast to list

Comment: @Valkyriee and spectarion - what you are suggesting is exactly doesnt work as stated in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you to @tesuya for setting me in the right direction
it seems that the real answer to this had nothing to do with pulling the Session values out
but rather a scoping issue such that
original full code looked like this:

```
@{
     string me = @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() + "-" + @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
     string jscript = "/Scripts/es/" + me + ".js";
}
```

and then when i added the session var it failed such that:

```
@{
    string me = @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() + "-" + @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    string jscript = "/Scripts/es/" + me + ".js";
    var rolz = Session["roles"] as List<string>;
}
```

however everything worked when i did this:

```
@{
    var rolz = Session["roles"] as List<string>;
    string me = @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() + "-" + @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    string jscript = "/Scripts/es/" + me + ".js";
}
```

therefore the offending line caused problems was this:

```
    string me = @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() + "-" + @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

which i still havent figgered out why 
but that is a question for another post...

(above said in the tone of conan the barbarian)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to use `UserManager.GetRoles` & put it into `HttpSessionState` should be like this:

```
Session["roles"] = UserManager.GetRoles(uid).ToList(); // stores List<string>
```

The assignment above stores `List<string>` into session variable, then you can retrieve list of roles there:

```
@{
    var rolz = Session["roles"] as List<string>;
}
```

Note that [`UserManager.GetRoles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497498(v=vs.108).aspx) method returns `IList<string>` which may different from `List<string>`, so it requires `ToList` method to get proper `List` type.

Reference:

[Asp MVC: How get roles from ApplicationUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975075/asp-mvc-how-get-roles-from-applicationuser)

Comment: thank you tetsuya for the start.  i didnt consider using a loosely typed "rolz" however the second List<string> now gives me the same generic type err which i cannot get away with as loosely typed

Comment: ps @tetsuya - the reference you included does not deal with pulling lists from session while in the view which is the crux of my question - just with pull lists from user manager

Comment: I putting the reference as converting `IList<string>` returned from `GetRoles` to `List<string>` by using `ToList` - using `as` operator to extract the list returns null instead of `NullReferenceException` (check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035291/how-to-add-liststring-in-session-state & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194238/how-to-retrieve-a-generic-list-from-session).

Comment: @{var rolz = Session["roles"] as List<string>} is not working (pls see my updated question.  any direction as to a fix would be greatly apprec

Comment: If Intellisense keep treating `string` generic type argument like HTML tag (by adding `</string>`), perhaps you have broken/prematurely terminated code block/syntax at certain point in your view page. Check if relevant code block is properly scoped.